# Adding where condition on Parent Object when child object is root. JPA Criteria API

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have below method which prepares where condition for my query. 
I want to add where condition on Parent object, and child object is my Root.

How do I achieve this using JPA Criteria API.

Below is my existing code, currently the where condition on parent object is commented out.

```
 private void prepareSearchCriteria(
  Map<String, Object> filters,
  CriteriaBuilder builder,
  Root<Employee> employee,
  List<Predicate> predicates) {

if (filters.containsKey("employeeName")) {
  predicates.add(builder.equal(employee.get("employeeName"),filters.get("employeeName").toString()));
}

if (filters.containsKey("enp.deptName")) {
  // How do add this condition ?
  // predicates.add(builder.equal(employee.get("employeeName"),filters.get("enp.deptName").toString()));
}

}
```

Can anybody help me with this? I am new to JPA Criteria API.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using below code, basically Path is the attribute which you want to compare. so from root to the attribute you want to compare you have to create path and then you can add it to the predicate.

```
if (filters.containsKey("enp.deptName")) {
  Path<Object> path = employee.join("employee").get("deptName"); 
  predicates.add(builder.equal(path, filters.get("employee.deptName")));
}
```

Source 
[altuure](http://www.altuure.com/2010/09/23/jpa-criteria-api-by-samples-%E2%80%93-part-ii/)